# setAttributes does not apply foreground color, but bold and other formatting is retained

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to replace a word "allowance" with "Some text", after running the code, It will remove word allowance and apply "Some text" with same formatting as that of "allowance" but foreground color property is not getting set as that of original.I want Some text also in red color as shown in the screenshot

[image]

[image]

```
function retainFormatting() {
  var doc  = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var textToHighlight = 'allowance';
  var highlightStyle;
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var textLocation = {};
  var i;

  for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
    textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight);
    if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
      highlightStyle = textLocation.getElement().getAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset());
      textLocation.getElement().deleteText(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive());
      textLocation.getElement().insertText(textLocation.getStartOffset(),"Some text");      
      textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);      
    }
  }
}
```

before setting attribute at offset

[image]

after setting attribute it turns out to be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> [**getForegroundColor(offset)**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getforegroundcoloroffset)
>
> Retrieves the foreground color at the specified character offset.

And

> [**setForegroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setforegroundcolorstartoffset-endoffsetinclusive-color)
>
> Sets the foreground color for the specified character range.

Here is a sample code :

Getting Color from text

```
highlightColor = textLocation.getElement().getForegroundColor(textLocation.getStartOffset());
```

Applying color to text

```
textLocation.getElement().setForegroundColor(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);
```

I hope it helps. Goodluck :)

Comment: @Jonathon: Yes, setForegroundColor does work where setAttributes doesn't. I'm looking into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
textLocation.getElement().editAsText().deleteText(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive());
textLocation.getElement().editAsText().insertText(textLocation.getStartOffset(),"Some text");
```

The [`.editAsText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#editastext) puts you into editing the contents of the rich text leaving the existing attributes as a 'wrapper'

Alternatively, try replacing the text rather than deleting and inserting

```
paras[i].replaceText("allowance", "some text") // the first attribute is a regular expression as string
```

Comment: Hi Jonathon, But adding **editAsText** doesn't work, help!

Comment: Try replacing instead of deleting and inserting. Answer edited.

Comment: Problem is focused on setting the attributes and not replacing text, Replacing text has no control over startOffset and endOffset. Anybody Please focus on setting the attributes and set right.

Comment: Those offsets are only defined by findText. The reason I was looking at alternatives was to investigate if the specific methods used contributed to the observed problem. i.e. Isolated text not having the attributes of the parent paragraph such that there are none can apply etc. If there is a way to achieve what you want which avoids such a restriction all the better. Have you checked the contents of the `highlightStyle` to see if FOREGROUND_COLOR is in there and red?

Comment: As you said, Yes, but replaceText will replace in a paragraph, I want to limit at specific position only governed by selection with some criteria. Hence I do not want to use replaceText,

Comment: I observed the contents of the object before setting and after setting but after setting attributes it turns to null

Comment: I have attached the contents after setting

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this and it seems that setting `LINK_URL` alongside other attributes interferes with `FOREGROUND_COLOR`.

The following results in a black text color:

```
      var attrs = {
        "FOREGROUND_COLOR": "#ff0000", // should be red
        "LINK_URL": null
      };
      text.setAttributes(start, end, attrs);
```

The following results in a red text color:

```
      var attrs = {
        "FOREGROUND_COLOR": "#ff0000" // should be red
      };
      text.setAttributes(start, end, attrs);
```

In effect, if you don't need to set the link, remove the `LINK_URL` from the list of formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

@JSDBroughton Gave me an idea, which worked.
Try setting the attributes of the rich text object you get when calling `editAsText`. So instead of:

```js
highlightStyle = textLocation.getElement().getAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset());
textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);
```

Do:

```js
// Make sure you replace `asParagraph` with what you actually need
highlightStyle = textLocation.getElement().asParagraph().editAsText().getAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset());
textLocation.getElement().asParagraph().editAsText().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);
```

Edit: after playing around with this, seems like this only sometimes works. I still haven't figured out the pattern for when it does work and when it doesn't.